# Why can't I get an element of this list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list l that is composed of the following elements:

```
> l
$quad_freqs
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
sol 0.0002308597 0.004155474 0.00623358 0.02493248 0.02576132 0.0748037
          [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]     [,11]
sol 0.02493029 0.2318451 0.05612928 0.3593334 0.1916445
```

I know l is a list because I typed

```
> class(l)
[1] "list"
```

However, I can't get the elements of the list.  For example,

```
> l[[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
sol 0.0002308597 0.004155474 0.00623358 0.02493248 0.02576132 0.0748037
          [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]     [,11]
sol 0.02493029 0.2318451 0.05612928 0.3593334 0.1916445
> l[[2]]
Error in l[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
> l[[0]]
Error in l[[0]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

I even tried the single bracket operator, but that didn't work either:

```
> l[2]
$<NA>
NULL

> l[0]
named list()
```

How can I get the elements of the list?

This is my first time using R, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way that `l` gets printed, it appears to be a one element list whose first (only) element is a one-row matrix. Something like this:

```
l <- list(quadreps=matrix(rnorm(5), nrow=1))
l
# $quadreps
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.5060329 -0.6333043 0.6637485 0.7293132 -1.330237
```

To access elements *of* the matrix, you need to first extract it from the list, using either `$` or `[[]]`, and then further subset it. To extract the element in `quadrep`'s third column, for instance, use any of the following:

```
l$quadreps[1,3]
# [1] -0.9604139

l[["quadreps"]][1,3]
# [1] -0.9604139

l[[1]][1,3]
# [1] -0.9604139
```

Comment: If you want to understand the structure of an R object, `str` is your friend. `str(l)` shows you `List of 1 $ quadreps: num [1, 1:5] 0.9435 -0.0596 1.0032 1.6427 0.2678`

Comment: What @unique2 said. Also, after doing `str(l)`, you can continue to "drill down" into the object, trying things like `str(l$quadreps)`, `class(l$quadreps)`, etc. Note too that using `l[1]` returns a one-element list whose first element contains `quadreps`, whereas `l[[1]]` returns `quadreps` itself. A subtle but important difference that will also become clearer if you compare `str(l[1])` and `str(l[[1]])`.